# AWS CLI: How to set VPC of New Replication Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

`aws dms create-replication-instance` does not get VPC as an option. When I create a new instance it does not create it in the VPC I intend to create the replication instance in.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a subnet group first and then use that when you build your instance.

The `create-replication-subnet-group` derives the VPC ID from the subnets you use for input.  The documentation is vague but VpcId is output from the command.

The docs for that command state:

> Creates a replication subnet group given a list of the subnet IDs in a VPC.

Then use the `replication-subnet-group-identifier` as input for the `create-replication-instance` command.

**References**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dms/